# Alinear icono de fontawesme al lado izquierdo del texto

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Hola buenas tardes tengo una sección de servicios como se muestra en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que pasa es que quiero poner el icono de fontawesome del lado izquierdo del texto.

A continuación les muestro el código que tengo.

```html
<!-- Row -->
        <div class="row m-t-30 p-t-30 client-box">
            <!-- column  -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                <div class="no-block contador">
                    <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-3x"></i>
                    <div class="m-l-20">
                        <h3 class="font-light counter m-b-0">5000</h3>
                        <h6 class="text-muted font-13 text-uppercase">Clientes Felices</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- column  -->
            <!-- column  -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                <div class="no-block contador">

                    <div class="m-l-20">
                     <i class="fa fa-coffee fa-3x"></i>
                        <h3 class="font-light counter m-b-0">20</h3>
                        <h6 class="text-muted font-13 text-uppercase">Años de experiencia</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- column  -->
            <!-- column  -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                <div class="no-block contador">
                    <i class="fa fa-users fa-3x"></i>
                    <div class="m-l-20">
                        <h3 class="font-light counter m-b-0">200</h3>
                        <h6 class="text-muted font-13 text-uppercase">Personal dedicado</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- column  -->
            <!-- column  -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                <div class="no-block contador">
                    <i class="fa fa-trophy fa-3x"></i>
                    <div class="m-l-20">
                        <h3 class="font-light counter m-b-0">20</h3>
                        <h6 class="text-muted font-13 text-uppercase">Premios ganados</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- column  -->
        </div>
```

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes lograr lo que quieres agregando `display: inline-block;` a la clase `m-l-20` asi:

```css
.m-l-20 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Row -->
        <div class="row m-t-30 p-t-30 client-box">
            <!-- column  -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                <div class="no-block contador">
                    <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-3x"></i>
                    <div class="m-l-20">
                        <h3 class="font-light counter m-b-0">5000</h3>
                        <h6 class="text-muted font-13 text-uppercase">Clientes Felices</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- column  -->
            <!-- column  -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                <div class="no-block contador">
                    <i class="fa fa-coffee fa-3x"></i>
                    <div class="m-l-20">                     
                        <h3 class="font-light counter m-b-0">20</h3>
                        <h6 class="text-muted font-13 text-uppercase">Años de experiencia</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- column  -->
            <!-- column  -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                <div class="no-block contador">
                    <i class="fa fa-users fa-3x"></i>
                    <div class="m-l-20">
                        <h3 class="font-light counter m-b-0">200</h3>
                        <h6 class="text-muted font-13 text-uppercase">Personal dedicado</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- column  -->
            <!-- column  -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                <div class="no-block contador">
                    <i class="fa fa-trophy fa-3x"></i>
                    <div class="m-l-20">
                        <h3 class="font-light counter m-b-0">20</h3>
                        <h6 class="text-muted font-13 text-uppercase">Premios ganados</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- column  -->
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No me quedo claro si necesitas el icono al lado de ambos textos o no, de todas maneras si te sirve esta es mi solución que consta en cambiar de posición el tag `i`

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Row -->
        <div class="row m-t-30 p-t-30 client-box">
            <!-- column  -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                <div class="no-block contador">
                    <!--<i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-3x"></i>-->
                    <div class="m-l-20">
                        <h3 class="font-light counter m-b-0">
                        <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i> 5000
                        </h3>
                        <h6 class="text-muted font-13 text-uppercase">Clientes Felices</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- column  -->
            <!-- column  -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                <div class="no-block contador">

                    <div class="m-l-20">
                     <!-- <i class="fa fa-coffee fa-3x"></i> -->
                        <h3 class="font-light counter m-b-0">
                        <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i> 20
                        </h3>
                        <h6 class="text-muted font-13 text-uppercase">Años de experiencia</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- column  -->
            <!-- column  -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                <div class="no-block contador">
                    <!--<i class="fa fa-users fa-3x"></i>-->
                    <div class="m-l-20">
                        <h3 class="font-light counter m-b-0">
                        <i class="fa fa-users"></i> 200
                        </h3>
                        <h6 class="text-muted font-13 text-uppercase">Personal dedicado</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- column  -->
            <!-- column  -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                <div class="no-block contador">
                    <!--<i class="fa fa-trophy fa-3x"></i>-->
                    <div class="m-l-20">
                        <h3 class="font-light counter m-b-0">
                        <i class="fa fa-trophy"></i> 20
                        </h3>
                        <h6 class="text-muted font-13 text-uppercase">Premios ganados</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- column  -->
        </div>
```